# Dolphin accesses smb share, mount doesn't

Tags: samba, smb

my first question, please be gentle ;)

I'm trying to access a smb share at my work using kubuntu 14.10 (Kernel 3.16.0-31-generic). Dolphin can access the share if I type in the  *smb://ip/share*  in the address line, but

```
sudo mount //ip/share /media/share -o username=user,password=password,workgroup=workgroup
```

gives me a

```
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

To get the smb call in dolphin to work, I added the correct workgroup in smb.conf. I also added my username and password in  *system settings-> network -> sharing*  
Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Calling my admin didn't help. They are completely windows based and are not allowed to help with linux based problems.

*edit*

As suggested, after running

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ip/share /media/share --verbose -o user=user,domain=workgroup,pass=password
```

I get the following statement

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options:  
ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,unc=\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\share,user=user,,domain=workgroup,pass=********
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

can anyone make anything out of this?

Comment: Try running: mount -t cifs //ip/share /media/share --verbose -o user=user,password=password,domain=workgroup and see what the error may be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was fixed, when I added the *sec=ntlm* option

Comment: You need to specify where you added `sec=ntlm`-- in your smb.conf? as a command line argument to Dolphin? Be specific.